# How to add button in flutter which has a icon and a stopwatch in a Row with submit button to the right?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So, while learning flutter I am trying to add a Row which has two buttons.

-First to the left has an icon of play and pause, with a stopwatch(let's say it starts with 20 min left).

-On the click of that button, I am trying to show a pop-up screen coming from the bottom.

-Secondly, a button on the right having text as submit and on click function would be the same i.e opening a pop-up from the bottom of the screen.

Image of mock I am trying to replicate:
[image: mock]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't share any code, I am giving you an idea how to do it.

Create a `Row` widget like:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.pause), onPressed: _showSheet),
    Text("19:26"),
    Spacer(),
    FlatButton(onPressed: _showSheet, child: Text("Submit")),
  ],
)
```

And define `_showSheet()` method as:

```
_showSheet() {
  showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (_) => YourImplementation());
}
```